# Is there any evidence that Theremon 762's name was based on a theremin?

Tags: short-stories, name-significance, isaac-asimov

In Isaac Asimov's novel and short story (short story later expanded) *Nightfall*, there's a character named "Theremon 762".

The whole novel is about darkness and innate fear, and a [theremin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin), a type of musical instrument, is known for being used to convey a sense of suspense or fear.

Is there any evidence that Asimov based Theremon 762's name on the instrument?

Comment: There is nooothing online that has both the word "theremon" and "theremin" in it. Except for an old forum post about how someone picked their username.

Comment: @Emrakul hm, okay. The answer may end up being "no" or just no answers, but this was just a thought I had.

Comment: I've never heard of theremins being known for conveying suspense and fear

Comment: @DForck42 you've been living under a rock.

Comment: The closest that Asimov and the theremin are associated seems to be that people like to hear its sound while listening to or reading his stories.

Comment: @Bookeater or _playing it_ while reading them :P

Comment: @Riker &Dimension X of course :-)

Comment: @DForck42 It makes the "ooooooooo" sound for ghosts in a lot of TV etc. See also https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=spooky+theremin+music

Comment: @DForck42 It creates fear in me every time I hear one

Comment: I don't think it will help in this specific case, but you could try to read Asimov's essays on naming in his sci-fi from the *Gold* collection.